# Custom RPM name in Sonatype Nexus OSS Yum repo

Tags: rpm, nexus

I've setup Nexus OSS. I am trying to add RPMs to YUM repository. 
The issue is, it changes the name of the RPM file based on the folder structure. I don't want this behaviour.
I am looking to build YUM repo on the tunes of,

http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/epel/6/

RPM file name should be independent of directory structure.

Comment: For Nexus 2, the documentation is available at http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/yum.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36685674/304690

Comment: What is the expected directory structure for any RPM package for a hosted NPM repository? I am able to curl and download, but unable to install using yum install command. I followed the steps mentioned here - https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/formats/yum-repositories